# Reccomendation for website analysis tools

Tags: analytics

I am asking here because I have very little experience with data gathering/analysis and this has proven to be a complicated matter.

So far I am using GTA to gather data from a few Wordpress sites and GA for analyzing them individually. My doubts about GA arose when i tried setting up a report that I imagined would be standard procedure, but it proved to be impossible within GA.

To give an example, one thing that I wanted was to make a simple table with Pages as dimension and a metric with values that are the following calculation: Page Views / total events of a specific label.

I learned from some other discussions on this network that one could use google spreadsheet to merge reports and make any calculations desired, but this requires one to understand spreadsheet coding and I don't have time to learn all that. I would much prefer something more intuitive to work with.

By the looks of it there are lots and lots of analytics tools out there and my hopes are that some would be better suited for me. I would very much appreciate some recommendations to cut time and to avoid bad ones. Free tools are preferred, but reasonable prices can be considered.

Answer (score 1):

Use google analytics and if you are developer there are many APIs for google analytics. It is very easy to use I recommend it. Many sites are using it.

Answer (score 1):

SimilarWeb may suite your needs. It's a decent, somewhat free tool for analysing traffic metrics across demographics and categories.